Breezing Forms - go to top of form, not page
The current behavior is that it goes to the top of the page when you change the page: https://lenkraddesign.eu/oferta/kierownice-samochodow-osobowych
Is there any way to make it scroll to the top of the form rather than page? Or alternatively stop the scrolling altogether? I don't want to use the single page layout.

The optimal way
I just randomly found the optimal way to do it:

Go to Manage Scripts part of Breezing Forms.
Switch package to FF - it's not too noticable that's there.
In the following scripts: Next page, Previous page, Validate and next page and Validate previous pages change:

self.scrollTo(0, 0);

to:
element.form.scrollIntoView(true);

or anything alike. Then, as a side note, you can easily control the scroll position, if needed, with:
.bfFormDiv form {
  scroll-margin-top: 10.5em;
}

Old answer
Here's my ugly workaround - for each first input element on a page, add this Advanced -> Initscript:
function ff_gornyPasek_init(element, condition)
{
  switch (condition) {
    case 'pageentry':
      element.scrollIntoView(true);
      break;
    default:;
  }
}

where gornyPasek is the field name. If there's no input, you can add a hidden one.
If anyone has anything less abysmal without the need of doing something like this for each page, I'll gladly accept another answer.
